# Does convolution preserve strict log-concavity?

Tags: convolution

Suppose $f, g$ are *strictly* log-concave functions.
Then the convolution $f * g$ will also be log-concave.
However, will it also be *strictly* log-concave?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follows by combining:

[1] Total Positivity of Mean Values and Hypergeometric Functions. B.C. Carlson and J.L. Gustafson. SIAM J. MATH. ANAL. Vol. 14, No. 2, March 1983.

[2] Convolutions of Logarithmically Concave Functions. Milan Merkle. Univ. Beograd, Publ. Elektrontehn. Fak. Ser. Mat. Vol. 9, 1998.